# Log4j2: How to print all object parameters in log

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

I would like to print all objects arguments as part of log message in Log4J2. For instance if I call

```
logger.info("Hello World 3", true, false, "'3 object params means we invoke ... method'");
```

The result is that only the following is logged

> Hello World 3

I would like something like

> Hello World 3 true false '3 object params means we invoke ... method'

I can do this

```
logger.info("Hello World 3 {} {} {}", true, false, "'3 object params means we invoke ... method'");
```

But then I have to remember to add the correct number of {}. Also I have refactored code using regexp from other log-framework, so I have lots of statements looking like the first with object parameters but not {}.

It is possible to change the message adding a * or []? I have not been able to find this in Log4j2 documentation [Messages](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/messages.html) or [Layout Patterns](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout)

Comment: Why dont you just simple use + operator?

Comment: This is a dynamic approach: `Arrays.toString(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, "anything else").toArray());`

Comment: If you use any of the above solutions please be aware, that this will spend time on CPU with some string operations, even if the logger is configured to not print log level info. If you do so, you should encapsulate your call with `logger.isInfoEnabled()`

Comment: @tejoe Thank you for answering the above questions for be. To elaborate: StringBuffer objects will be created and string built before log method is called. The log-statement will impact performance, even when logging is disabled. Its also in the javadoc. The problem is clearly seen then a class-file is decompiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please raise a feature request for this on the Log4j2 Jira issue tracker.

Two considerations: 
1. The implementation would have to add spaces between the supplied extra parameters. 
2. Need to take care not to break the existing logic that extracts any last Throwable parameter.

Comment: Thx. I have created this issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1353